# SpringSecurity Android Facebook and Google token authentication

Tags: android, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm migrating backed for android application from NodeJS to Spring Boot.

I successfully implemented web based oAuth login using packages:
`compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2")`

This authentication is done by filter

```
OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
            path);
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
    filter.setRestTemplate(template);
    filter.setTokenServices(new UserInfoTokenServices(
            client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(), client.getClient().getClientId()));
    return filter;
```

But I want to authenticate client using Android SDK [Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) and [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) tokens.

I managed to do this in node JS using Passport libraries [passport-google-id-token](https://github.com/jmreyes/passport-google-id-token) and [passport-facebook-token](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token)

I searched a lot but I didn't find any answer how authenticate in Spring Security oAuth, using application tokens (id_token)